# What does "it" refer to in "Percy wouldn't recognize a joke if it danced naked in front of him wearing Dobby's tea cozy."?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, pronouns

> "Don't let Percy hear you saying that," Hermione said, smiling slightly.
>
> "Yeah, well, Percy wouldn't want to work for anyone with a sense of humor, would he?" said Ron, now starting on a chocolate eclair. "Percy wouldn't recognize a joke if **it** danced naked in front of him wearing Dobby's tea cozy."
>
> *Harry potter and the goblet of fire*

I guess Ron is being sarcastic here, but I don't understand the exact meaning of the sentence especially what "it" refers to here.

Is it "a joke"?

Comment: Yes, he wouldn't recognize a joke, if the joke danced naked in front of him.

Comment: PG Wodehouse was very fond of a variant of this: "...if it was served to him on a platter with watercress round it", which appears numerous times in his stories.

Comment: The trope takes many forms.  At the opposite end of the spectrum from watercress on a platter: *He wouldn't recognize a good idea if one bit him in the ass.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It* in that sentence refers back to *a joke*, of course. There is a simple rule that states that personal pronouns (those are words like *he*, *she*, *it*, *they* etc.) usually refer back to the closest antecedent that they follow. An antecedent is an earlier word, phrase, or clause to which another word, especially a pronoun of some kind, refers back. In our case here, *a joke* must be the antecedent of *it* since they are apart from each other by just one word.

So, the point that they're trying to make with this is that Percy probably doesn't have a very good sense of humor because even if a joke were to become a human, took its clothes off and preformed an erotic dance right in front of him, he still wouldn't be able to tell that it's a joke. Something like that. I think you get the idea.

Comment: I just thought I was wrong since *joke* certainly cannot dance naked like a human.. Thanks!